# Changing "render" key from "plain" to "json" causes server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, active-model-serializers

Consider the following code

```rb
class AuthenticatedController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from InvalidCredentials, with: :unauthenticated

  def current_user
    raise InvalidCredentials
  end

  private

  def unauthenticated(_error)
    render plain: { error: 'text' }.to_json, status: :unauthorized
  end
end

class UsersController < AuthenticatedController
  def show
    render json: current_user
  end
end
```

When I request Users#show it renders `{"error":"text"}` just fine.

But if I change `unauthenticated` to

```rb
  def unauthenticated(_error)
    render json: { error: 'text' }, status: :unauthorized
  end
```

And the resource responds with `{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}`.

The stack trace:

```
Started GET "/api/v1/user" for ::1 at 2021-08-25 12:24:30 +0300
Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 214)

InvalidCredentials (InvalidCredentials):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:in `show'
app/controllers/authenticated_controller.rb:in `current_user'
app/controllers/authenticated_controller.rb:in `unauthenticated'
```

So calling `render json: {}` in the handler causes the same error to be raised again. But at the same time `render plain: ''` does not.

What happens when I change key from `plain` to `json` and how to make it respond with `:unauthorized` instead of server error when using JSON?

Comment: What's there in stacktrace?

Comment: @AmitPatel I've added the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) library for rendering JSON.
It uses `scope` option of `render` as a method name to invoke and it is `current_user` [by default](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/serializers.md#controller-authorization-context). So the library invoked `current_user` method again when I called `render json: ...` leading to the error.

I've changed `unauthenticated` method to

```rb
  def unauthenticated(_error)
    render json: { error: 'text' }, status: :unauthorized, scope: nil
  end
```

and it began to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have given, the problem is most likely how you use `rescue_from` The request which triggers the error have to be a JSON request in order for this to work. For example if you try to login from a form it's usually by default a HTMl request. A way to confirm this is to use `raise request.inspect` in the controller method. If this is the case, there is no easy fix and you will have to fix the request it self or just support both.